Prove $T/U$ being upper-triangular given $T$ and $U$ being upper-triangular
This is a problem from LADR4e 5C12 (b).
Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $T \in L(V)$ has an upper-triangular matrix
with respect to some basis of $V$. $U$ is a subspace of $V$ that is invariant under $T$.
Prove that the quotient operator $T/U$ has an upper-triangular matrix with respect to some basis of $V/U$.
I've thought about this for quite a long time and came up with two possible ways, but all got stucked.
a) Show that the basis of $U$ with respect to which $U$ is upper-triangular, $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_m$ can be extended to a basis of $V$ and maintaining upper-triangular.
b) Use a previous theorem and try to prove that the minimal polynomial of $V/U$ can be completely factored.
However, I cannot figure out the way to extend the basis in a). There was a previous exercise showing that the minimal polynomial of $V/U$ times the minimal polynomial of $U$ is a polynomial multiple of the minimal polynomial of $V$, which sort of goes to the converse.
Many thanks.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Do you understand that over $\mathbb C$ every square matrix is similar to an upper triangular one?  (I am looking for a very basic result here not Jordan Forms.)  When a characteristic polynomial is guaranteed to split linearly your preceding argument should work for any field but there's nothing wrong with focusing on $\mathbb C$ first.

Suppose $p(z)$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$, then $p(T/U)(v+U)
=p(T)v + U = 0_{V/U}$. This show that the minimal polynomial of $T/U$ must be a factor of $p$. Since $p$ factors completely, so does the minimal polynomial of $T/U$.
